# Execute opencover with nunit from .net code

Tags: nunit, opencover

I am trying to create a asp.net website which will be as an entry point for all the nunit and code coverage.

I am able to run nunit against unit tests from the website using nunit api.

Is it possible to execute opencover with nunit using opencover api?

If yes, it would be real great for some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCover is a console app and is simple to launch from any build framework.

The [OpenCover](http://github.com/opencover/opencover) source code has code for a dedicated msbuild task that you could use as a starting point.